# If I have the $Q$ matrix, can I somehow find the $P$ matrix?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I have this $Q$ matrix $$\left[\begin{array}{rrrr} -6& 1& 2& 3\\ 4& -15& 5& 6\\ 7& 8& -24& 9\\ 10& 11& 12& -33 \end{array}\right]$$

I was just wonering if there is any way to change the $Q$ matrix to transition $P$ matrix?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that by $Q$ matrix you mean the generator of a continuous-time Markov chain 
where the transition matrix for time $t$ is the [matrix exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential)  $T(t) = \exp(t Q)$ and you want $P = T(1) = \exp(Q)$, the transition matrix for a discrete-time Markov chain such that $P^k = T(k)$ for positive integers $k$.  There are lots of ways to compute it.  See in particular  Moler and val Loan, ["Nineteen Dubious Ways to Compute the Exponential of a Matrix, Twenty-Five Years Later"](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/cv/researchpdf/19ways+.pdf).